# faster FFT issue in Python using pyqtgraph

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, fft, pyqtgraph, multiprocess

As you can see below I have a program that uses pyqtgraph to display a spectrum of two signals on some noise using numpy. It may well be I am pushing the limits here. I am using a sample rate of 300000 to put some pressure on things. None-the-less I saw no improvements in splitting up this app using multiprocess or threading from putting the code lines in the signal() function from having it all under the update() function. I also tried pyfftw, which showed no improvement when substituting that in for np.fft. I show 1 core always at 100% so I suspect multiprocess (or threading) may not really be working the way I expect it either. Depending on your computer at aa rate 300000 it updates and pauses and updates and pauses. I would like to hit something like 2400000 smoothly without the pauses between updates. Anyone know how I can speed this up please?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import numpy as np
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue
from numpy import arange, sin, cos, pi
from scipy.fftpack import fft, rfft
import pyqtgraph as pg
import sys
import multiprocessing

class Plot2D():
    def __init__(self):
        self.traces = dict()

        #QtGui.QApplication.setGraphicsSystem('raster')
        self.app = QtGui.QApplication([])
        #mw = QtGui.QMainWindow()
        #mw.resize(800,800)

        self.win = pg.GraphicsWindow(title="Basic plotting examples")
        self.win.resize(1000,600)
        self.win.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: Plotting')

        # Enable antialiasing for prettier plots
        pg.setConfigOptions(antialias=True)

        self.canvas = self.win.addPlot(title="Pytelemetry")
        self.canvas.setYRange(-10, 100, padding=0)

    def start(self):
        if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
            QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()

    def trace(self,name,dataset_x,dataset_y):
        if name in self.traces:
            self.traces[name].setData(dataset_x,dataset_y)
        else:
            self.traces[name] = self.canvas.plot(pen='y')

## Start Qt event loop unless running in interactive mode or using pyside.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Plot2D()
    i = 0

    def signal():
        rate = 300000 # sampling rate
        t = np.arange(0, 10, 1/rate)
        sig = np.sin(2000*np.pi*4*t) + np.sin(2000*np.pi*7*t) + np.random.randn(len(t))*0.02 #4k + 7k tone + noise
        return sig

    def update():
        rate = 300000 # sampling rate
        z = 20*np.log10(np.abs(np.fft.rfft(signal()))) #rfft trims imag and leaves real values
        f = np.linspace(0, rate/2, len(z))
        p.trace("Amplitude", f, z)

    timer = QtCore.QTimer()
    timer.timeout.connect(lambda: update())
    timer.start(10)
    p.start()


    t1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=signal)
    t1.start
```

Comment: Are you mainly concerned that the FFT is slow, or that the plotting of the result in pyqtgraph is slow, or both?

Comment: The issue is that something somewhere seemed to be blocking, I slowed the sample rate right down and it seems to work on in real time but not as fast as I would have expected, no matter what I did the execution always seemed to put pressure on 1 core only I could not get multiprocess or threading to spread the load around the cores. In contrast if I just demodulate the signal I can do so at a much higher rate then down sample to audio but displaying it at the full bandwidth was not possible. I could for example use baudline ok at the full rate but not with pyqtgraph.